# Angular 2 Dependency injection does not work

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am writing an application on angular 2 and I would like to cache some data. When you go to each page, I constantly call the service designer instead of passing an existing object.

1. **component 1:**

   ```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { DataService } from '../services/globaldata.service'
   import { User } from '../models/User';

   @Component({
           selector: 'Campaigns',
           templateUrl: './campaigns.component.html',
           providers: [DataService]
   })

   export class CampaignComponent implements OnInit 
   {
     public user: User;

     constructor(private dataService: DataService) 
     {
       this.user = dataService.getData();
     }
     ngOnInit() {
     this.user = this.dataService.getData();
     }
   }
   ```
2. **component 2:**

   ```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { DataService } from '../services/globaldata.service'
   import { User } from '../models/User';

   @Component({
       selector: 'Wallet',
       templateUrl: './wallet.component.html',
       providers: [DataService] 
   })
   export class WalletComponent implements OnInit {

       public user: User;

       constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
           this.user = dataService.getData();
       }
       ngOnInit() {
           this.user = this.dataService.getData();
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Service:**

   ```
   import { User } from '../models/user';
   export class DataService
   {
   private data: User;

   getData(): User {

       return this.data;
   }
   setData( price: number) {

       this.data = new User(price);
   }
   constructor() {
       this.data = new User(this.randomInteger(1,1000));
   }


   public randomInteger(min:number, max:number) {
       var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
       rand = Math.round(rand);
       console.log(rand);
       return rand;
   }
   ```

The console produces a random value each time it navigates, but the dependency injection should, in my opinion, cache the value. What could be the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Your service is missing `@Injectable()`:

It should look like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService
{ ... }
```

Comment: Tried to add, but didn't help.  Still, the object is created every time again

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question is dependency injection, that does what you need to do. Looking at your code, it is performing how it should be, not sure what you mean `object is created everytime`. If you are trying to get a single instance of the object you are doing it wrong.

Comment: If you are adding it to the [provider] from each component, it will be created one instance per component. You should move this to the providers array from a NgModule, maybe the root module or a shared module, if you want a single instance.

Comment: `@Injectable()` is only *really* required when the service itself depends on other service being injected via the constructor. Most of the time we add it to a service by convention only.